# Linux + Windows dualboot, both encrypted

Tags: windows-7, encryption, grub, arch-linux, veracrypt

i want to dualboot w7 32bit and arch linux (antergos) on an old netbook (lenovo s10-3). I've installed windows but i need some help with next steps.
I found this guide that i plan to roughly follow:
https://techblog.mastbroek.com/all-articles/dualboot-encrypted-windows-and-ubuntu/6/
but with antergos and veracrypt instead of ubuntu and truecrypt so what i think i will have to do is:

1. install windows
2. encrypt boot drive
   so far so good, i installed windows and i'm about to start encrypting it
3. install antergos with built-in encryption and with grub on /boot instead of in mbr
   there is a slight problem with this one, i installed antergos before and there doesn't seem to be a choice of where grub is installed
4. repair veracrypt bootloader in mbr and drive header if needed
5. repair grub if needed

Can someone help me throu steps 3-5? I'm not sure what exactly should i do after encrypting windows, I'm also fairly confident with setting up partitions and encryption in antergos but after that, i have no idea how to get those two encrypted systems working together. It's an old laptop, it has one hdd and no efi.
Please help.